# Indentify Needed/Uneeded Classes In JAR

Tags: java, jar, class-library

I am distributing a Java application as a JAR but it depends on a few extra Apache libraries. All told the libraries increase the size of the JAR sixfold. I don't need the entire library and I want to remove anything that is not needed by my code.

Is there a way to identify the classes that are needed? I *could* go through the source for all the classes I called and check their dependencies but that is just a pain considering the libraries are from 6 separate JARs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to eliminate any unneeded classes within the distributed jars.  You might need to customize the process to handle dependencies that cannot be discovered at compile time (e.g. due to reflection).